# Replacing in class types and variables in dotnet templates

Tags: .net, templates, dotnet-cli

Lets say I have a file with a peace of code below in my template

```
private readonly IMyEntityRepository _myEntityRepository;
```

Then I have a configuration

```cs
"symbols": {
     "entity": {
        "type": "parameter",
        "datatype": "string",
        "replaces": "MyEntity",
        "fileRename": "MyEntity",
        "defaultValue": "MyEntity"
     }
  }
```

and run the command like

```
dotnet new service-template -n RuleService --entity Rule
```

In the end I get

```
private readonly IRuleRepository _myEntityRepository;
```

but want to have

```
private readonly IRuleRepository _ruleRepository;
```

Is that possible to achieve using just a single parameter?